# How to calculate the impact on dependent variable with two independent variables with different sample sizes

Tags: regression, correlation, sample-size, regression-coefficients

I am researching a framework using regression analysis. With the beta coefficients I now want to calculate the correlation between my variables with the influence of another. 
So I have the beta of 0,465 of the independent on the dependent variable with a sample size of 176; additionally another independent variable has an impact on the relationship with beta 0,733 and the sample size 30. How do I calculate the final impact considering both different sample sizes?

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Could you explain what you mean by "final impact"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You have to include both variable in the model in order to do this, and the model has to be on one set of data.